# Use process.env in Angular 5 environment

Tags: angular, angular5, devops, ng-build

I try to build an Angular 5 application with the standard `ng build --prod` command, and I want to set the basic API-Url in the `environment.prod.ts` to a value dependent on my `process.env` variables.

This is my file:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    apiUrl: `${process.env.BASE_URL}` || 'http://localhost:8070/',
};
```

But when I try to build the application the following error occurs:

`ERROR in src/environments/environment.ts(7,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.`

How can I set my API-Url according to an env variable when building the application?

Comment: You could write a little node script that generates your environment file before you do your `ng build`.

Comment: You can update the webpack build to use `DefinePlugin`, or you could use https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-inline-environment-variables/ -- regardless, you will have to change your build pipeline.

Comment: I just used a JSON file - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/sharing-secret-environment-variables-with-google-cloud-build-and-angular-universal-7e3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update**

Per the comments below the original answer was not entirely clear -- Angular is built with Angular CLI, which is a node application, but you aren't able to access `process.env` directly from within the app during that build process, as it's not *processed* as a Node application.

The concepts stay pretty much the same, but it's important to understand the above.

**Original**

You won't have access to `process.env` at compile-time of the Angular code.

`process.env` is available to `Node` applications, which an Angular application is not.

You have several options:

1. Make a task of some sort in your build pipeline to update the environment file with the correct value if it truly needs to be dynamic.
2. Just hardcode it and make several environmental files to match each of your environments.  You can specify your environments in your angular-cli.json.

Option number 2 sounds like it might be right for you. In that case, you want to put this in your angular-cli.json:

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "path/to/dev/env",
    "prod": "path/to/prod/env"
}
```

and build your app with `ng build --env=prod`.

Here is more in-depth information:
https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

Comment: How do you access this?

Comment: You need to make process.env available to your Angular application.  If it's there at build time, you can use gulp or something to put it in a constant Angular can access.  You could make a request to the server at runtime to get them as well, if that's needed.

Comment: I don't think put **secret** environment variables in environment.ts file is correct.

Comment: @novaline correct, you shouldn't put secret env vars in your environment files.  But if you're shipping something to the browser, then it wouldn't be very secret anyway.

Comment: What about ANgular 7?

Comment: @chrispy, yes it won't much of a secret on the browser. But what if I don't want to put my **secret** environmental variables in the **repository**? This would be my application for the **env** file.

Comment: @RinMinase that's a separate discussion entirely, but you could pull from a vault or something at build time, or have a different protected shared space for storing those.  This question would be applicable to secrets that are inherently exposed as they are going to the client.

Comment: @chrispy, well, that would seem to be the only option as trying to compile angular with a custom webpack with the included config file is still not working. Anyways, thank you! Cheers! :)

Comment: > process.env is available to Node applications, which an Angular application is not


Angular CLI, which is what performs the build, is absolutely a Node application.  So this is not the reason it doesn't work.  It must be due to however `ng build` is processing it.

Comment: @obsessiveprogrammer I've added a section to the answer to make sure that's clear to anyone coming across this answer.