# Is there an getEnvironmentMode or equivalent convenience method in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

There is a isDevMode convenience method is Angular, as described here: https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

```
      import { Component, OnInit, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
```

Is there a convenience method to get the actual environment mode?  Like prod, dev, mock, etc?

I know I can add an extra variable in environment.ts for it.  But if we are running the app with --environment mock already, I don't want to have to set environmentMode=mock in environment.mock.ts

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get ENV variables on Client which is browser. You can send request to a rest service on your server, and get environment from backend, then response back to client

```
app.get("/rest/getenv", function(req, res) {
    var env = process.env.ENV_VARIABLE;
    res.json({result: env});
});
```

**EDIT**

**No**, there is no such thing to get environment Mode.

Comment: Not sure if you have misunderstood my question.  My question is regarding getting the environment mode when you do ng serve or do ng build.  the one after the --environment flag

Comment: yes you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496438/use-process-env-in-angular-5-environment

Comment: Still not what I am looking for.  It actually points back to the isDevMode article.  I am looking for environmentMode...

Comment: No there is no such thing