# Read values from environment variable Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to read the environment variable property using

> process.env['KEY_TO_READ']

This KEY_TO_READ i am setting up in the environment variable. But, its not taking up at compile time only i am getting the below error:

```
Cannot find name 'process'.
```

Somewhere i read like in angular app we cannot use process because it will be defined at runtime. Is it correct ? If yes then can anyone suggest how i can achieve this . I don't want to use angular-cli environment file options.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49496438/9766215)

Answer (score 13):

You ll have your environment file as,

**environment.ts:**

```
export const environment = {  
  production: false,
  envName: 'dev',
  KEY_TO_READ: 'test'
};
```

**It is exported so you can import it:**

```
import { environment } from './environment';

export class MyappAppComponent {  
  title = 'myapp works!';
  KEY_TO_READ = environment.KEY_TO_READ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i dont want to put some variable inside the code.

Comment: even you can use directly `environment.KEY_TO_READ` without storing in variable

Comment: @Saravan Lets say i want to read the ip to call the backend but as it changes i don't want to build and change the ip in code instead i want to change it in the environment variable. By this i don't have to build my file again

Comment: for the same purpose they have given two files one for `development` and the other for `production`, if you change in `production` build is required bit for development, it is not requiered.

Comment: [this link will help you](https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659) check **A process.env Problem** part of that

Comment: @Rohitesh, checked that link?

Answer (score 2):

You may use it like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

let KEY_TO_READ = environment.KEY_TO_READ;
```

It will pick the dynamic environment variable which you have defined at the time of application build.

Comment: i don't want to keep the scope of variable inside the code that's why i was thinking to go with approach like this

Comment: [This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/properly-set-environment-variables-for-angular-apps-with-gulp-ng-config) may help.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a secret key inside the env file won't make it private it will remain public thus I have a solution for you where you could read a key from environment variable without mentioning it in `environment.ts` to do this you'll need to install few dependencies.
these are the versions that are compatibles with `Angular 7` probably few other you are free to try new versions.

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.2.0",
"@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.2.1",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.3"
```

run

```
npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack@7.2.0 @angular-builders/dev-server@7.2.1 @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.3
```

To be able to use custom web pack will have to add some changes to `angular.json` under your `root` folder

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig":{
          "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js" 
        },



"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
```

create a file `extra-webpack.config.js` under your root folder and add this inside:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        KEY_TO_READ: JSON.stringify(process.env.KEY_TO_READ),
    }
})]
}
```

**UPDATE**

> This also could cause you some troubles so if it works without the typings.d.ts it's better because you'll probably get an error later when everything is working fine `declare var process nodejs.process error  Variable 'process' must be of type 'Process', but here has type 'Process'.` in that case just use the node types and delete the file `typing.d.ts`

If you try to use these variables, angular will complain about types definition. To get around that, create a file called `typings.d.ts` (`d` extension for `declare`)  inside of your `*src/` and put the following in there:

```
declare var process: Process;

interface Process {
 env: Env
}

interface Env {
 KEY_TO_READ: string
}
```

it's better to centralize your config in only the `environment.ts` file and use it this way

```
const KEY = `${process.env.KEY_TO_READ}`;
export const environment = {

production: false,
key : KEY
};
```

In order to make this work you need to run your app by running this command

```
KEY_TO_READ="TEST" npm start
```

you are now able to use the env variable inside your angular app in a `someservice.ts`

```
const Hash = `${environment.key}`;
export class SomeService{
console.log(Hash) //should display "TEST" in your console
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems like defining `declare var process: Process;` complains because it was defined before in `index.d.ts` as `declare var process: NodeJS.Process;`. Instead it's better to [choose a different variable name as suggested](https://medium.com/@zeeyoo52/i-resolved-the-compilation-error-by-tweaking-the-tsconfig-json-76bf1333105c).

Comment: @Kamel Mili istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead: i am getting this error while downloading dependency any idea?

Comment: What was the purpose of installing `dotenv`?

Comment: What about production environment as if i build with command --build?