# add a dynamic variable to frontend application start in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an application and I have 2 screen. Let's call them 1 and 2.
What I want to do is that when I run the app like so:
yarn start
I will show screen 1 and when I run 
SOMETHING yarn start
it will show screen 2.
To way I handle the actual viewing of the screen is not the problem. 
I am just trying to understand how to tell my app to know that SOMETHING is defined. What I mean is that for example:

```
return process.env.SOMETHING ? <div>2</div>: <div>1</div>;
```

I am guessing that I should use an env variable here but I am not sure. How can I tell my app that the SOMETHING variable was defined when I ran the app so show screen 2 instead of 1. Is there a way of doing this without webpack? Thanks

Comment: I think this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496438/use-process-env-in-angular-5-environment

Comment: If angular put that value in environment file